# JavaScript instance level decorators

Tags: javascript, decorator, babeljs

Is it possible to define a decorator that would be exposed at an instance level in the current iteration of the proposal

For example

```
function once(target, name, descriptor) {
  let {get} = descriptor;
  var called = false, result;
  if (typeof get === "function") {
    descriptor.get = function() {
      console.log(called);
      if (!called) {
          result = get.apply(this, arguments);
          called = true;
      }
      return result;
   }
  }
  return descriptor;
};

class X {
    @once
    get y() {
      return Math.random();
    }
}

var x1 = new X;
var x2 = new X;


// Should be false
console.log(x1.y !== x2.y)
```

I'm wanting behaviour similar to doing

```
class X2 {
  constructor() {
     // Set descriptor manually for this instance
    let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(X2.prototype, 'y');
    let d = Object.assign({}, descriptor);
    once(X, "y", d);
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'y', d);
  }
  get y() {
    return Math.random();
  }
}
```

[Babel REPL example](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=false&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true&code=function%20once(target%2C%20name%2C%20descriptor)%20%7B%0A%20%20let%20%7Bget%7D%20%3D%20descriptor%3B%0A%20%20var%20called%20%3D%20false%2C%20result%3B%0A%20%20if%20(typeof%20get%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22function%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20descriptor.get%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!called)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%20get.apply(this%2C%20arguments)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20called%20%3D%20true%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20return%20descriptor%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass%20X%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%40once%0A%20%20%20%20get%20y()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Math.random()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20x1%20%3D%20new%20X%3B%0Avar%20x2%20%3D%20new%20X%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(x1.y%20!%3D%3D%20x2.y)%0A%0Aclass%20X2%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Set%20descriptor%20manually%20for%20this%20instance%0A%20%20%20%20let%20descriptor%20%3D%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(X2.prototype%2C%20'y')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20d%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20descriptor)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20once(X%2C%20%22y%22%2C%20d)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperty(this%2C%20'y'%2C%20d)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20get%20y()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Math.random()%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20y1%20%3D%20new%20X2%3B%0Avar%20y2%20%3D%20new%20X2%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(y1.y%20!%3D%3D%20y2.y))

Answer (score 5):

Decorators only run once when the class is defined, but that doesn't mean that the definition-time logic can't set up the function to do stuff per-instance. In this case, you could memoize the value by defining an instance-specific property inside the prototye-level getter;

```
function once(target, name, descriptor) {
  let {get, writable, enumerable} = descriptor;
  if (typeof get === "function") {
    descriptor.get = function() {
      const value = get.apply(this, arguments);
      Object.defineProperty(this, name, {
        value,
        writable,
        enumerable
      });

      return value;
   }
  }
  return descriptor;
};
```